# Ag-Grid: Color match when filtering

Tags: javascript, material-ui, ag-grid, highlight, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG-Grid to display a value. I was wondering: Is there a way to color the matched cell when quick filtering?

E.g. I have

```
[
  { firstName: 'Tom', lastName: 'Doe', company: 'Tesla' },
  { firstName: 'Tim', lastName: 'Boulder', company: 'Tommy Hilfiger },
  { firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Miller', company: 'D3' }
]
```

and I search for `om` that Ben isn't displayed any more and the table colors `Tom` for Tom and `Tommy Hilfiger` for Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way: get the quickfilter text with

**gridOptions.quickFilterText**

and then use it in a cellclass function:

```
var colDef = {
  name: 'First name',
  field: 'firstName',
  cellClass: function(params) { 
    return params.value.indexOf(this.gridOptions.quickFilterText) > -1
      ? 'value-found-class'
      : 'no-value-found-class'
  );}
}
```

If the cellClass function does not get retriggered, listen to the **filterChanged** event:

```
gridOptions.onFilterChanged = function() {
  gridOptions.api.refreshCells();
}
```

Check out the params for refreshCells:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

Comment: This doesn't work, because the function doesn't re - run if the `quickFilterText` changes 

Comment: Thank you very much  You helped me a lot!

Comment: gridOptions.quickFilterText is undefined for me

Answer (score 1):

We can use **cellRender** property to highlight the filtered text in the following way

**Name.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles, Typography } from '@mui/material'


const customStyles = theme => ({
    dotLabel: {
        fontSize: '14px',
        margin: '7px 0px',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        wordBreak: 'break-all',
    }
})

const Name = ({ name, highlight, classes }) => {

    if (!highlight.trim()) {
        return <div>{name}</div>
    }

    const escapeRegExp = (str = '') => str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, '\\$1')
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${escapeRegExp(highlight)})`, 'gi')
    const createMarkup = html => {
        return { __html: html }
    }
    const data = name.replace(regex, match => `<span style="color:#1e99fa;">${match}</span>`)

    return <Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(data)} className={classes.dotLabel}/>
}

Name.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default withStyles(customStyles)(Name)
```

**column.js**

```
const cellRender = params => {
    const value = isArray(params.value) ? !isEmpty(params.value) && params.value.join(', ') : params.value
    const filterField = !isEmpty(params.api.getFilterModel())

    if (filterField) {
        const filterInput = params.api.getFilterModel()['name'].filter

        if (filterInput && value) {
            return <Name name={String(value)} highlight={String(filterInput)} />
        }
    }
    return value
}


export default [
    {
        cellRenderer: cellRender,
        field: 'name',
        headerName: 'Name',
        headerTooltip: 'Name',
        tooltipField: 'name'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky solution for React (btw the issue in ag-grid's pipeline is AG119):

1 Enable `reactNext` and give a `frameWorkComponents` value:

```
<AgGridReact
  animateRows={true}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}
  multiSortKey="ctrl"
  onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  quickFilterText={searchValue}
  reactNext={true}
  rowData={contacts}
/>
```

2 Define `frameWorkComponents:`

```
import HighlightCellRenderer from './HighlightCellRenderer';
// ...
const frameworkComponents = {
  highlightCellRenderer: HighlightCellRenderer,
};
```

3 In your `colDefs` add the `cellRenderer`:

```
cellRenderer: 'highlightCellRenderer',
```

4 Lastly, create your custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getSearchValue } from '../../layout/header/search-value-reducer';

function HighlightCellRenderer({ value }) {
  const searchValue = useSelector(getSearchValue);
  if (searchValue && value.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
    return <strong>{value}</strong>;
  }
  return <span>{value}</span>;
}

export default HighlightCellRenderer;
```

In my case I'm getting the `searchValue` using Redux.

Note: Using custom cells like this might mess with the performance and disable features such as auto resize:

```
//  This won't work with the custom cells:
function onFirstDataRendered({ columnApi }) {
  var allColumnIds = [];
  columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
    allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
  });
  columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
}
```